# Is there a way to efficiently update a grid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a project site that is essentially a music visualizer.
https://218studio.com/space_trip.php

Tutorial was taken from "The Coding Train"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKB1hWWedMk

The problem that I'm running into is that the algorithm to compute the and update the grid in the draw() function is running in n squared time.

```
  for (var y = 0; y < rows - 1; y++) {
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    var xoff = 0; 
    for (var x = y; x < cols - y; x++) {
      terrain[x][y] = map(noise(xoff, yoff), 0, 1, -100, 100);
      xoff += 0.2;
      vertex(x * scl, y * scl, terrain[x][y] * size);
      vertex(x * scl, (y + 1) * scl, terrain[x][y] * size);
    }
    yoff += 0.2; 
    endShape();

  }
```

The current site takes about 30% of my gpu's capacity to run smoothly. However, that is on a 2080ti with a 10700 processor. When demoing for my friend the grid lags his laptop so much the sound does not play properly.

Solutions that I've tried implementing locally are to reduce the grid density and to only render the squares visible on the computer screen, but that only reduces the gpu usage by about 4%.

Comment: FWIW it takes nearly 88% of my NVIDIA GTX 1070 - but at least it's not overheating and it does keep up with the music.

Comment: That's actually pretty useful information. It'll let me know approximately the processing power needed to run properly.

Comment: Without looking at the code, I would assume there is some render loop going on.  Usually this will run at the video refresh rate.   But your not forced to do this, you could maybe alter the render loop to run at lower frame rates.  120fps is starting to be common, so having the option to change this would have the biggest effect on CPU/GPU usage, eg. 30fps would then instantly reduce CPU/GPU usage by a quarter.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea! For the particular package I'm working on (p5.js) the default fps is 60 fps. Reducing it to 30fps degrades the animation quality too much, but 45fps is actually a decent middle ground. The change resulted in a drop of 8% gpu usage to a total of 22% gpu usage. Thanks for the suggestion!